# Duplicates with different tag

Tags: discussion

There's been a couple of instances recently of people taking a question that's just been asked and answered and re-asking the question with a different winning criterion. Can we (or should we) close these as duplicates?

There's already a tendency here to take a question that's been popular and rehash it numerous times with barely significant variations. To use a (probably poor) analogy - it's like watching a film and then watching the director's cut (156 seconds of previously unseen footage!) immediately afterwards.

Comment: Oh, the irony. :-)